# Best way to hash passwords in PHP 5.3.5

Tags: hash, php

What is the best way to hash passwords in PHP 5.3.5? Since in this version doesn't have `password_hash()`.

Comment: Best idea is to update - that version of PHP has been out of support for a while (unless it's part of a long term support linux distro), so any security flaws in it will not be fixed. It's even too old for the compatibility library mentioned in the PHP manual on password_hash!

Comment: But the problem is that I have a site in a hosting server that only support that version. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Yeah, it's not an uncommon problem. Might be worth speaking with them to see if they can update the PHP version - would be bad if you are doing things properly and then get breached due to a flaw in outdated server software.

Comment: Agreed; complain to them, and realize there are likely a lot of vulnerabilities that were patched in later versions.  Or find a new hosting provider that keeps up with patches!

Comment: There is a compatibility pack available for PHP versions 5.3.7 and later, made by one of the guys behind PHP, Anthony Ferrara. You can find it [here](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat).

Comment: I suggest you to use the hash_hmac() function. It generates the hash with an additional salt to prevent rainbow table hacking and it also makes brute-force attacks much longer.

Comment: You can find a cheap VPS (e.g. LowEndBox), that's often cheaper than shared hosting, but allows you to control your OS and any software you need.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you can update the version of PHP it's best to do so, but sometimes shared hostings have older versions of PHP like yours which do not support `password_hash()`.

[Phpass](http://www.openwall.com/phpass/) seems to suit well in this case.

> phpass (pronounced "pH pass") is a portable public domain password hashing framework for use in PHP applications. It is meant to work with PHP 3 and above, and it has actually been tested with at least PHP **3.0.18** through **5.4.x** so far. (PHP 3 support is likely to be dropped in next revision.)
>
> The preferred (most secure) hashing method supported by phpass is the
> OpenBSD-style Blowfish-based bcrypt, also supported with our public
> domain crypt_blowfish package (for C applications), and known in PHP
> as CRYPT_BLOWFISH, with a fallback to BSDI-style extended DES-based
> hashes, known in PHP as CRYPT_EXT_DES, and a last resort fallback to
> MD5-based salted and variable iteration count password hashes
> implemented in phpass itself (also referred to as portable hashes).

---

Note: if you happen to have PHP version >= 5.3.7 you can also use [password_compat](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat)

Comment: is this essentially bcrypt? I know is possible to use bcrypt package without upgrading

Comment: Don't forget to increase the work factor if you can!

Comment: @silverpenguin Yes, I believe that is correct.